# Urlpatterns in django are not redirecting(why are responses not displaying?)

Tags: python, django

**I created this but when I try to run the server, it only shows the django website. I have turned it off, as it's not a problem in firewall either. **

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('home')

def contact(request):
    return HttpResponse('contact')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home),
    path('about/', contact),
]

**I also added it to apps**

INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'accounts',
```

]

Comment: what is the name of your file?

Comment: app is called accounts

Comment: project is called crm1

Comment: Ya, I should have seen your INSTALLED APPS

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSCrp_0_sxdC6SCpkRxi3MU5XzagQHhwS You can try these video lectures if you are beginning with django, I learned from here but docs are the best source to learn once to know something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your project name is project and app name is app

Inside you project directory,

```
project/urls.py

from .app import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home),
    path('about/', views.contact),
]

app/views.py


def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('home')

def contact(request):
    return HttpResponse('contact')
```

Comment: that didnt help unfortunatelly

Comment: this guy manages to display it without putting the functions into the views file https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvTyqta3OJo&t=7s

Comment: When you try to access the page, did you add the `/` at the end?
`(e.g. 127.0.0.1:8000/about/)`